# Text encoding and column arranging give UnicodeEncodeError in 2.x

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

***SOLVED***
this was a Unicode issue in 2.x and a non-issue when you upgrade to 3.x

I am trying to learn webscraping with Python and BeautifulSoup to export data into readable spreadsheets. I have two questions:

**Problem 1:** I have hit a snag multiple times while trying different sites when encountering a symbol such as the trademark symbol (tm) how do I either remove this or encode this to a form that will allow pandas to output the data into csv?

**Problem 2:** When I do export data (by omitting rows that contain characters referenced in Problem 1) the columns aren't necessarily in the order I'd like. How can I specify the order in which the columns are listed?

Problem 1 attempted solutions:

- Omitting rows that contain unrecognized characters (works but not optimal).
- Recalling the variable and using .encode('utf-8') doesn't work

Problem 2 attempted solutions:

- Rearranging the variables within the df.
- Adding a number value prior to column name (again works but isn't optimal)

.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

stocksym = []
stockname = []
stockprice = []
data = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?offset=0&count=100')

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

div =soup.find('div', { 'id': 'scr-res-table' })
table = div.find('table')
tbody = table.find('tbody')

for tr in tbody.find_all('tr'):

        sym = tr.find_all('td')[0].text.strip()

        stocksym.append((sym))

        name = tr.find_all('td')[1].text.strip()

        stockname.append((name))

        price = tr.find_all('td')[2].text.strip()

        stockprice.append((price))

df = pandas.DataFrame({

        "1Sym": stocksym,

        "2Name": stockname,

        "3Price": stockprice

        })

df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)

print(df)
```

I expected the output of the top 100 stocks to be exported to a csv in a column order of Sym, Name, Price.

Actual results have been stoppage at the first encountered non-supported character and requiring me to put numbers prior to the column names to get the desired order.

Comment: Python 2 or 3? Python 3 handles Unicode better. What is the exact snag about the trademark symbol (tm)? Is it simply being mangled, or does it throw an exception (if so please post it)?

Comment: You said in comment on the deleted answer that your issue is an exception *"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfa' in position ...: ordinal not in range(128)"*

Comment: 2.7... I will upgrade to a newer version and try again.

The tm symbol threw the same error as the special u character, when scraping steam stats page for top 100 games in a different script.

Comment: Make your life easy and migrate to Python 3 like the rest of us did years ago. You'll find the Unicode handling much nicer.

Comment: I can't get requests to install on 3.6, why I defaulted to writing this in 2.7 which already had requests installed.

Comment: `requests` installs just fine on 3.x; if you get a Windows permissions issue then just see the Q&A on that. Btw [the current version of 3.x is 3.7.2](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-372/). Honestly 3.x will solve so many issues in scraping you will weep with joy. Why make your life complicated...

Comment: Alright, I have upgraded to 3.6 currently and it is functioning perfect. Was failing to remember to run cmd as admin when installing pips, so that's all sorted. Thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: Windows permissions strike again... can you please edit a note into your question saying this was a Unicode issue in 2.x and a non-issue when you upgrade to 3.x?

Comment: Edit posted. Also, is there a way I can close this question's responses so folks don't think it hasn't been solved?

Comment: RichBiggs: you can't close it yourself, but us other users can vote-to-close as off-topic: simple issue/ debugging help (or whatever). Happy you solved it. Enjoy 3.x!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `read_html` function in `pandas` would be easier and will encounter less problems.  Simply install `lxml` library if you encounter an error, pandas uses this library for HTML processing.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

data = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?offset=0&count=100')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div', { 'id': 'scr-res-table' })
table = div.find('table')

df = pd.read_html(table.prettify())[0][["Symbol", "Name", "Price (Intraday)"]]
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-16")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a timely reply.
This functions but still errors at problem 1 referenced above. Due to the ú character in Itaú Unibanco Holding S.A..

Comment: @RichBiggs I'm not getting that error.  What url are you using?

Comment: I copied your code and created a new .py for it.

Comment: Error is too long to paste all but it ends with UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfa' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Screen shot of error:

https://gyazo.com/b3be7a1089ca9e3f39824e40d465f790

Comment: RichBiggs please post your actual exception in your question above. Post the text, not a screenshot. In the question body, not down here in comments on an answer.

Comment: I apologize for the incorrect placement.